# Automatic Updates For Private And Commercial Themes?

Tags: theme-development, themes, updates, automatic-updates

Is there any way to get wordpress to check for, download private theme updates?

I found this plugin for private plugin updates....

http://w-shadow.com/blog/2010/09/02/automatic-updates-for-any-plugin/

I'm looking for the same thing but for themes.

Comment: If you don't want to roll your own solution, you can use kernl.us for hosted plugin updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite possible. I've been doing this for years with my Version Checker plugin.

I do not distribute it openly, but in essence it checks a private version API , and then tosses the extra results into the update_core, update_plugins and update_themes site transients. WP then takes it seamlessly from there courtesy of the WP patches I supplied when I was developing it.

Answer (score 1):

I have personally used [this](http://w-shadow.com/blog/2011/06/02/automatic-updates-for-commercial-themes/) one and it is really good and awesome.

Using this library is easy you just have to add a piece of code to your functions.php file and host the theme.zip and a JSON file containing the new version numbers and other basic info somewhere in web publicly accessible.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a hosted solution that you don't have to manage, check out [Kernl](https://kernl.us). Its a service that provides the infrastructure for updating plugins and makes it easy to integrate into your own plugins.

Comment: Please do not copy/paste answers (this question isn't even about plugins) and disclose your affiliation if talking about products you are involved with.

Answer (score -2):

I've found [this](http://konstruktors.com/blog/wordpress/2538-automatic-updates-for-plugins-and-themes-hosted-outside-wordpress-extend/) that seems it might do the job.