# Creating a theme update notification api

Tags: theme-development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatic Updates For Private And Commercial Themes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5220/automatic-updates-for-private-and-commercial-themes)

I am trying to create a notification system for my theme that will talk to my server via a simple api that simply lets people know when there is a new update. How would I create the api and incorporate it into my theme?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few options out there:

1. [Jeremy Clark's Theme/Plugin Update Notifier](https://github.com/jeremyclark13/automatic-theme-plugin-update)
2. OR [WP-Updates](http://wp-updates.com/) which is... pretty freakin sweet IMHO

Thanks!