# Global Parent theme for all sites

Tags: multisite, parent-theme

I have 15 different wordpress sites installed on my server. They are independent installations , not  multisite. I have developed a parent theme and copied it in all sites. Now whenever I have to make a change in parent theme, I have to access parent theme of all sites and make changes in each theme. Is it possible that I can globalize this parent theme such that I do change on one place and it reflects on all 15 sites (Without using Multisite feature). Though I wrote a php script that copies parent theme in all sites but not satisfied since I have to call that script everytime.

Comment: How would one stand-alone WordPress install know about another one? Why don't you want to use MultiSite, which would make your problem a non-issue?

Comment: They gave me 15 stand alone wordpress sites to work. :(

Comment: Then I would search the site for how to hook into the WordPress Update API, host the Theme somewhere yourself, and let the individual sites poll for updates. [See this question, for example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5220/automatic-updates-for-private-and-commercial-themes)

Comment: thanks. Will check it out. Can you make this comment your answer. I may consider accepting it :D.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate directory and a (sub) domain for your themes.
Lets say the domain is `themes.example.com`, and the directory is `/extra/wp-themes/`.

Now let all your installations use the new theme root. Or just do [the same for plugins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/15484/73) to manage all plugins from one place too.

Registering a new theme root is not possible with constants, you will need a plugin like this:

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Local Theme Roots */

add_filter( 'theme_root_uri', 't5_switch_theme_root' );
add_filter( 'theme_root',     't5_switch_theme_root' );

/**
 * Create a custom theme directory.
 *
 * @wp-hook theme_root
 * @wp-hook theme_root_uri
 * @author  Thomas Scholz, http://toscho.de
 * @param   string $in URL or path
 * @return  string
 */
function t5_switch_theme_root( $in )
{
    if ( 'theme_root_uri' === current_filter() )
        return "http://themes.example.com";

    // If we made it so far we are in the 'theme_root' filter.
    $new_root = '/extra/wp-themes';
    register_theme_directory( $new_root );
    return $new_root;
}
```

Be aware there is a bug in the WordPress’ theme updater that doesn’t let you update themes from the wordpress.org directory when you are using a custom theme directory. You have to run the updates for such themes either manually, or use my patch from [Ticket #22501](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22501) until WordPress 3.6 is out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on linux and all the sites are on one server you can use [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)

If your deployment location of the theme is /home/me/mytheme add an symbolic link in each site's theme directory to point to it

/home/site1/wp-content/themes/mytheme -> /home/me/mytheme

Once done every time apache will access the file /home/site1/wp-content/themes/mytheme/x.php the OS will load the file /home/me/mytheme/x.php, therefor a change in the /home/me/mytheme/x.php file will have an immediate impact in all of the sites.