# Automatic updates of plugins and themes outside of wordpress.org

Tags: plugins, themes, updates, private

I'm finding it surprisingly difficult to find any info on standardized ways of updating a "private" plugin that does not exist in the wordpress.org repositories. I've seen -- and bought -- plenty of premium plugins that often have updates available via the WordPress admin, so it's obviously possible.

Is there a "WordPress" way of doing this? I feel like there should be an API to handle this, and would expect at least some tutorials on how to do this, but I'm having trouble finding something useful. I'm very much interested to bake this functionality into a plugin that I'm developing. I'm not interested in third-party plugins that do this for me, because I don't want the dependency.

What are the current options for non-dot-org plugins and themes to be updated via admin?

Comment: A few weeks ago I found this. Not that I've used it, but I think it's what you want. http://wp-updates.com/

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5220/automatic-updates-for-private-and-commercial-themes

Comment: If you don't want to roll your own solution, you can use kernl.us for hosted plugin updates.